# React onClick receiving an inline style

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to code a sidebar in React, and when I click on each element of this sidebar, it gets activated. however, I want to override the default UI library active styles with an inline style, however my code here in onClick function doesnt compile and gives me an error. how to do this?

```
class Sidebar extends Component {
    state = {
      navActive : '0'
    }

  render () {
    return (
      <NavPanel dark style={{ backgroundColor: '#2d2e2e', height: '100vh', float:'right'}}>
        <NavTitle style={{ fontFamily: 'IranSans', textAlign: 'Center' }}>
       لوگو اینجا قرار بگیرد
        </NavTitle>
        <NavSection>
          <NavSectionTitle />
          <NavSectionTitle />

          <NavLink key='2' style={linkStyles.base} rightEl={<GiIceCube style={linkStyles.Icon} />} 

          className={this.state.navActive === '2' ? 'active' :' ' }

          onClick={() => this.setState({ navActive:'2' }, style={{ borderStyle:'solid',
          borderWidth:'0px 10px 0px 0px',
          borderColor:'green'}})}>

           داشبورد
          </NavLink>

        </NavSection>
      </NavPanel>

    )
  }
}

export default Radium(Sidebar)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameters of `setState` is a callback performed once state has been changed.

So you have to specify your style depending of the state.

```
      <NavLink key='2' rightEl={<GiIceCube style={linkStyles.Icon} />} 

      className={this.state.navActive === '2' ? 'active' :' ' }

      onClick={() => this.setState({ navActive:'2' })}
      style={ this.state.navActive !== '2' ? {linkSyles.base} : {
      ...linkStyles.base,
      borderStyle:'solid',
      borderWidth:'0px 10px 0px 0px',
      borderColor:'green'}
      }
       >
```

Comment: this is correct but it overrides my previous non active styles (style={linkStyles.base} ) how can I fix that one?

Comment: @Dorian Oups, excuse me, I didn't see it before, here is a corrective